# screen capture into Keynote

Tags: macos, screen-capture, iwork-keynote

Is there some utility or Service that will allow me to screen capture from a window or rubber band **directly** into Keynote **without first storing the document in a file**?

I would like to do this with the "Services" command, if possible.

One way to do this would be to make the screen shot happen, then put the screen shot on the pasteboard, then do a paste command. But I am not familiar with the approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> will give you a magical pointer; you click-drag rectangle; the rectangle will then be screenshotted directly to the clipboard; switch to keynote and do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste.  rinse and repeat.

Comment: Very cool. I wish I could do it completely within Grab, but this is great. Is there anywhere that this is documented?

Comment: Does not work on Keynote 6.2.2 on mavericks 10.9

Answer (score 0):

Grab.app in Utilities directory is the program you are looking for. It helps you make screen shots that can be saved in a tiff and included in keynote. What the real name of the Grab.app is, I can not tell, because in German it is called "Bildschirmfoto" (screen picture).

Comment: see comment to question above.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/15646/underused-mac-os-x-gui-features), you have [(at least)](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X) the following screen capture options:

- Whole screen: Cmd+Shift+3
- Select a specific area with mouse: Cmd+Shift+4
- Directly to clipboard: Cmd+Ctrl+Shift+3
- with Cmd+Shift+4, you can also select one window by tapping the space bar

The screen captures are saved to the desktop in png, unless of course you choose directly to clipboard. [Here's](http://snowleopardtips.net/tips/everything-you-need-to-know-about-screen-captures.html) a guide to changing the formats of the screen captures (pdf, jpg and so on.)

Comment: Hi; I edited the question to make it clear that I don't want to store the screenshot in a file first. I have to make hundreds of screen shots. There should be a way to do this with services or some kind of applescript or macro.

Comment: Add a control press to all of those.

Comment: None of these are working in Mavericks 10.9